# Debugging/Stepping into a package module via cabal repl

Tags: debugging, haskell, ghc, cabal, ghci

So I have the following code from [Preventing caching of computation in Criterion benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29340053) and my aim is to be able to step from `main` directly into the function `defaultMain` in `Criterion.Main` :

```
{-# OPTIONS -fno-full-laziness #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-cse #-}
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
module Main where
import Criterion.Main
import Data.List

num :: Int
num = 100000000

lst :: a -> [Int]
lst _ = [1,2..num]

myadd :: Int -> Int -> Int
myadd !x !y = let !result = x + y in
  result

mysum = foldl' myadd 0

main :: IO ()
main = defaultMain [
  bgroup "summation" 
    [bench "mysum" $ whnf (mysum . lst) ()]
  ]
```

and the cabal file is :

```
name:                test
version:             0.1.0.0
build-type:          Simple
cabal-version:       >=1.10

executable test
  main-is:             Main.hs
  build-depends:       base >=4.8 && <4.9,
                       criterion==1.1.0.0
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  ghc-options:         "-O3"
```

(using ghc 7.10.1 and cabal 1.22.0.0).

If from within `cabal repl` I try to set a breakpoint in criterion I get the following error :

```
*Main> :break Criterion.Main.defaultMain
cannot set breakpoint on defaultMain: module Criterion.Main is not interpreted
```

Furthermore if I try to `add` the package I get the following error :

```
*Main> :add *Criterion

<no location info>: module ‘Criterion’ is a package module
Failed, modules loaded: Main.
```

If I do within the directory `git clone https://github.com/bos/criterion`
and then add the following two lines to my cabal file :

```
other-modules:       Criterion
hs-source-dirs:      .
                 ./criterion
```

then upon doing `cabal build` I get the following errors :

```
criterion/Criterion/IO.hs:23:0:
     error: missing binary operator before token "("
     #if MIN_VERSION_binary(0, 6, 3)
```

so I suspect that I have to do a full on merge of the criterion cabal 
file with my cabal file above, which feels a bit excessive.

Is there an easier way for me to go about setting a breakpoint 
in Criterion, so that I can step (when debugging in cabal repl/ghci) directly from my source into criterion's source? Thanks

p.s. There is a related question at [Debugging IO in a package module inside GHCi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28570367) but unfortunately it did not help.

Comment: I don't know the answer to the `cabal` file part, but as far as I know, GHCi can *only* debug code in its internal bytecode format. In particular, you want to avoid natively compiling with `cabal build`, since the resulting `.o` files would be used by default instead of bytecode.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Thanks, I have managed to debug cassava before by "merging" the cabal files, which allowed me to seamlessly step from my application into cassava. However the same attempts with criterion results in a `criterion-1.1.0.0/cbits/time-posix.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol clock_gettime@@GLIBC_2.2.5 can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC`, which is what I am currently trying to solve!

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen : Ah it seems that the way to resolve the `time-posix.o` error in comment above is to add the option `cc-options: -fPIC`. So for the moment I can achieve the desired behaviour by merging the cabal files and adding `cc-options: -fPIC` to the resulting cabal file.

Comment: Great! This does sound like a generally useful tip. If you want you can post an answer to your own question describing how you solved it.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen : I posted the method below. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I managed to achieve the desired goal of being able to step (within `cabal repl`) from my code into the criterion source :

1. First do :

   ```
   mkdir /tmp/testCrit
   cd /tmp/testCrit
   ```
2. Download `criterion-1.1.0.0.tar.gz`
3. Unzip into `/tmp/testCrit`, so we should have `/tmp/testCrit/criterion-1.1.0.0`. In this directory we have `Criterion.hs` etc.
4. Then jump into the folder containing the criterion source and do :

   ```
   cd /tmp/testCrit/criterion-1.1.0.0
   cabal sandbox init
   cabal install -j
   ```

   Note that this creates a directory : `/tmp/testCrit/criterion-1.1.0.0/dist/dist-sandbox-782e42f0/build/autogen` which we shall use later
5. Back in `/tmp/testCrit` create a `Main.hs` file containing the benchmark code above and also the cabal file above, but merge it with the criterion cabal file contained in `/tmp/testCrit/criterion-1.1.0.0` in the following way. Note the main new additions are the lines :

   ```
   cc-options: -fPIC
   ```

   which allows one to run it in `cabal repl`, and the following 
   lines :

   ```
   hs-source-dirs: 
     ./
     ./criterion-1.1.0.0
     ./criterion-1.1.0.0/dist/dist-sandbox-782e42f0/build/autogen
   ```

   The full cabal file should then look like :

   ```
     name:                test
     version:             0.1.0.0
     build-type:          Simple
     cabal-version:       >=1.10

     executable test
       main-is:             Main.hs
       build-depends:       
         base >=4.8 && <4.9,
         aeson >= 0.8,
         ansi-wl-pprint >= 0.6.7.2,
         base >= 4.5 && < 5,
         binary >= 0.5.1.0,
         bytestring >= 0.9 && < 1.0,
         cassava >= 0.3.0.0,
         containers,
         deepseq >= 1.1.0.0,
         directory,
         filepath,
         Glob >= 0.7.2,
         hastache >= 0.6.0,
         mtl >= 2,
         mwc-random >= 0.8.0.3,
         optparse-applicative >= 0.11,
         parsec >= 3.1.0,
         statistics >= 0.13.2.1,
         text >= 0.11,
         time,
         transformers,
         transformers-compat >= 0.4,
         vector >= 0.7.1,
         vector-algorithms >= 0.4
       default-language:    Haskell2010
       ghc-options:         "-O3"
       c-sources: 
         ./criterion-1.1.0.0/cbits/cycles.c
         ./criterion-1.1.0.0/cbits/time-posix.c
       hs-source-dirs: 
         ./
         ./criterion-1.1.0.0
         ./criterion-1.1.0.0/dist/dist-sandbox-782e42f0/build/autogen
       cc-options: -fPIC
   ```
6. Then in the main directory do :

   ```
   cd /tmp/testCrit/
   cabal sandbox init
   cabal install -j
   ```
7. Then we can spin up a `cabal repl` and step directly into
   criterion ***from our `Main.hs` code*** :

   ```
   *Main> :break Criterion.Main.defaultMain
   Breakpoint 0 activated at criterion-1.1.0.0/Criterion/Main.hs:79:15-43
   *Main> main
   Stopped at criterion-1.1.0.0/Criterion/Main.hs:79:15-43
   _result :: [Benchmark] -> IO () = _
   [criterion-1.1.0.0/Criterion/Main.hs:79:15-43] *Main> :step
   Stopped at criterion-1.1.0.0/Criterion/Main.hs:(131,1)-(147,39)
   _result :: IO () = _
   [criterion-1.1.0.0/Criterion/Main.hs:(131,1)-(147,39)] *Main> :step
   Stopped at criterion-1.1.0.0/Criterion/Main.hs:(131,29)-(147,39)
   _result :: IO () = _
   bs :: [Benchmark] = [_]
   defCfg :: Criterion.Types.Config = _
   [criterion-1.1.0.0/Criterion/Main.hs:(131,29)-(147,39)] *Main> :step
   Stopped at criterion-1.1.0.0/Criterion/Main.hs:132:10-37
   _result :: IO Criterion.Main.Options.Mode = _
   defCfg :: Criterion.Types.Config = _
   ```